# Python Open Source Video Player To Dynamically Play a Stream of Consecutive Videos

Tags: python, video, pyqt, pyqt5, python-vlc

any help is much appreciated. I've been looking for a few days for something to meet the following use case. I need to open a single video player window which will play a dynamic stream of videos selected by an accompanying program. I'm on windows 10 but could probably find a way to use linux if needed.

So the flow would be as such:

1. Video 1 opens in the video player window.
2. On a queue sent by the same script which started the previous step, Video 1 is paused/stopped and Video 2 is played in this same window with a seamless frame to frame zero transition time.
3. The script in the background does some additional processing to decide whether it wants to next play Video 3, Video 4, or Video 5. Let's say the script chooses Video 5.
4. Now on conclusion of Video 2 we want to tell this same window to play video 5, again with seamless frame to frame zero transition or black screen.

Does anyone know how to do this? I've not been able to figure it out with python-vlc, OpenCV, or anything else! Please Help! Thanks!

I found this PyQt5 code ([How to play multiple clips of a video one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416396/how-to-play-multiple-clips-of-a-video-one-after-another) see ekhumoro's answer), which appears to play one video after another. However, the media is given to the window before calling app.exec()... How do I update the media source dynamically as the window is already open and playing media? AKA after app.exec() has been called?

Comment: really not an OpenCV/computer vision problem. your task is "just" to display a bunch of video frames (from various sources) at the right time. pick any GUI toolkit. they'll have examples of video playback.

Comment: Are you able to play a video at all in Python?

Comment: Not without packages, but there are plenty of packages you can import that open video players (like the ones mentioned above). @ChristophRackwitz could you be more specific? Maybe an example? Currently your response sounds more speculative of "I assume there is a solution out there"